# FlexSearch does not search in all indexes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, full-text-search

I am using the FlexSearch library for full-text search in the application I am developing. When the application starts, I add all the records in the database to the index. However, when I want to search, I cannot search in all fields. For example, I have a collection where songs are kept in my database, and the song name, album name and artist name are added while adding them to the index, but when I search for 'metallica master of puppets', no results are returned. I have shared my codes below.

```js
const trackIndex = new FlexSearch.Document({
    charset: 'utf-8',
    preset: 'score',
    document: {
        id: 'id',
        enrich: true,
        index: [
            {
                field: 'title',
                tokenize: 'full',
            },
            {
                field: 'album',
                tokenize: 'full',
            },
            {
                field: 'artist',
                tokenize: 'full',
            },
        ]
    },
    cache: true,
})
```

```js
const tracks = await Track.find({}, 'title album').populate({
    path: 'album',
    select: 'title artist',
    populate: {
        path: 'artist',
        select: 'name',
    }
})
```

```js
tracks.forEach(track => trackIndex.add({
    id: track._id,
    title: track.title,
    album: track.album.title,
    artist: track.album.artist.name,
}))
```

I tried to search by combining all the fields I added to the index. For example, I combined them into `[songname][artistname][albumname]` and deleted all the spaces between them. However, when I make a query as above, another song in that album comes out at the top.